# Time Formats (such as yyyy MM dd hh mm ss zzz (UTC))

Tags: settings, time, format

Does the elementary OS provide flexibility in time formats (for example, a format such as yyyy MM dd hh mm ss zzz (UTC)) similar to those that are available in Kubuntu 14.04?

Comment: It depends where do you want to use these formats…

Answer (score 1):

No, time and date are set according to your language.

[image]